# Getting unknow graphics folder under assets while decompiling APK in Android

Tags: android, android-assets

While decompiling APK, I am getting certain folder inside assets which are not recognisable from where it is getting into the APK:

[image]

graphics and gfx folder are the one which have different svgs and jpg files.

How can we backtrack from where these folders or dependencies are getting added to the APK? or How to track the source of the files coming under assets folder?

Comment: It's seem so hard to find something on web about that. Maybe you have an external module with some graphics?

Comment: what's its content? expand it

Comment: @user2342558 It has multiple vector, jpg icons and upon searching in the code I couldn't find it's usage anywhere

Comment: Its possible that some direct or transitive dependency is adding that folder.

Comment: @Darshan How can I debug which dependency is actually adding that folder?